# Automator, for copying camera cards

Tags: finder, automator, camera

gurus and general tech gods.
I'v been fiddling with automator to try and make the process of copying camera cards and renaming its root folder and specific contents (the mp4's) to reduce the problems when linking media across different non linear edit suites.
I have the copy and rename the folder part working.
But then I want to be able to find just a particular extension in the copied folder and add the date to the front of them.[image]
My current workaround is adding 4 "get folder contents" actions as this Sony camera hides the mp4's 4 folders deep.
Untitled being the "camera card" in this example
[image]

Any help appreciated, I have no skills in programming or life.

Thanks,
OCN

Comment: you are a genius. I had tried filter but it was always crashing. the pause has solved it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear why you need four **Get Folder Contents** *actions*, when checking **[√] Repeat for each subfolder found** should get everything within the *folder* passed to that *action*. That said... RE: "I want to be able to find just a particular extension in the copied folder" -- Have you tried using a **Filter Finder Items** *action*? **Notes:** Some **Finder** related *actions* rely on **Spotlight**, and when processing something copied as a part of the *workflow* one may need to add a **Pause** *action* to allow indexing to occur before proceeding.

As a test, I created the **Untitled** *hierarchical folder structure* shown in your second screenshot with just the highlight *folders* and the **C0001.MP4** *file*. The *example* **Automator** *workflow*, below, without the **Pause** *action* the **C0001.MP4** *file* would not be found as the rest of the *window* runs to quick for the **Spotlight** indexing to have indexed the copied *folder* from the **Copy Finder Items** *action*.

[image]